# Delete All List Items Sharepoint 2013 REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, http-delete

I need to delete all the Items in a Sharepoint List using REST API.

How can I achieve this?

I can delete a single Item using:
"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items('ID')"

I tried to remove the ID but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

```
function deleteItem(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "If-Match": "*"
    },
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyList')/items",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var items = data.d.results;
        for(var item in items){
            var url = "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('MyList')/getItemById(item.ID)"
            deleteItem(url);
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to make one delete call for each item in the list, using a URI like you showed above, passing in each ID in succession.  If there are LOTS of items in the list, it would likely be cheaper and faster to delete then recreate the list itself.

Comment: Ok, so I should GET all the items in the list and call a DELETE for each. :( I think I will go for delete the list. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. But you should know, that here can be exception in your list. I had problem with list after using this code. I deleted all items, but my ListCount properties set to -3. I recomend use batch request for forming and execute request. It will be more quickly and safely

```
window.I = 0;
deleteFunction();

function deleteListItem(listTitle, listItemId, type)
{
    try
    {
    var listItemUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/items(" + listItemId + ")";
    var itemPayload = {'__metadata': {'type': type}};

    $.ajax({       
       url: listItemUri,
       type: "POST",   
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
          "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
          "If-Match": "*"
       },success :function(){
           console.log("deleted " + window.I);
           window.I++; 
           deleteFunction();
           },
           error: function (data) {
           window.I++; 
           deleteFunction();
          }
    });
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("error" + window.I);
        window.I++;
    }
}

function deleteFunction()
{
    try
    {
        if(window.I > 1000) return;
        deleteListItem('ListName',window.I,'SP.Data.ListNameListItem');
        console.log("deleted " + window.I);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("error" + window.I);
        window.I++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the list and re-create, then other PA flows will break.

Just select the items from the list in PA
Then add an apply to all and in there:

```
_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('[List]')/('outputs('Get_items')?['body/value']')
```